# How to test for convergence for the harmonic series with irregular (binomial) sign changes?

Tags: convergence-divergence, divergent-series, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

How would you test for convergence with a series such as this using the alternating series test?

$1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{7}...-\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{11}...+\frac{1}{15}-....$

I have attempted to find a summation equation for this by grouping in different ways in order to use the alternating series test but I can't find a way to group these in a logical way. Is there a grouping that would allow for analysis of this series using the alternating series test?

Comment: It appears that the sign changes are happening logically. The series alternates signs, but extends the length by 1 every time the sign changes. 1 positive, 2 negative, 3 positive, 4 negative, 5 positive, etc.

Comment: I would suggest grouping consecutive terms with the same sign, then attempting to apply the alternating series test.

Comment: For the alternating series test you need to look at the limit as n goes to infinity. The part I'm struggling with is a way to represent this series using n. I can see that each term decreases but the limit is where I'm getting caught up.

Comment: You didn't define a series but only its first few terms... And [partial summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) shows $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{a_n}}{n}$ converges whenever $\lim_{N \to \infty} N^{-c}\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^{a_n} = 0$ for some $c < 1$.

Comment: @IanBaughman Have you tried grouping terms as I suggested?  Can you see the pattern?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I noticed that the denominator forms a factorial but this breaks down at the grouping of $\frac{1}{11}+....+\frac{1}{15}$

Comment: See also my comment at Robert Israel's answer

Comment: I edited the title thinking this was an improvement. If it is now too specific or misleading please rollback that edit.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm interpreting this correctly: you have one $+$ term, then two $-$, three $+$, four $-$, etc.  The start and end of a run of $2k+1$ $+$ terms are $1/(2 k^2 + k + 1)$ and $1/(2 k^2 + 3 k + 1)$ and the start and end of the next run of $2k+2$ $-1$ terms are $-1/(2 k^2 + 3 k + 2)$ and $-1/(2 k^2 + 5 k + 3$.
Thus the sum of these two runs is at least

$$ \dfrac{2k+1}{2 k^2 + 3k + 1} - \dfrac{2k+2}{2k^2+3k+2} = \frac{-k}{(2 k^2 + 3k + 1)(2k^2+3k+2)}$$
 and at most

$$ \dfrac{2k+1}{2 k^2 +k + 1} - \dfrac{2k+2}{2k^2+5k+3} = \frac{-k}{(2 k^2 + 3k + 1)(2k^2+3k+2)} = \frac{6k+1}{(2k+3)(2k^2+k+1)}$$

Thus in any case it is bounded in absolute value by $C/k^2$ for some $C$, and thus the series converges.

Comment: I get with pari/gp using the shortcut-definition for the binomial-expression `x.b = 1+binomial(1+x,2) `  (so for instance `4.b = 1+binomial(5,2)=11`) and using the `psi()`-function for partial-sums of harmonic numbers for some $N$ for instance `N=5;psi(0.b)+(-1)^N*psi(N.b)-2*sum(k=0,N,(-1)^k*psi(k.b))` an alternating sequence of partial sums with decreasing terms. Euler-summation or using `sumalt()` gives a value of about $  0.517100379042$