# Alternating sum with ever increasing range of equal signs

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider this special form of an alternating sum

$$s=1-(\frac{1}{2})+(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4})-(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7})+(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{11})-(\frac{1}{12}+...+\frac{1}{16})+...$$

Notice that the ranges of equal signs increase linearly.

I wonder if the sum is convergent or not, and if it is convergent what is the result.

Edit by Rushba Mehta:

The explicit form of the series is $$1 - \sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n-15}-1}2\rfloor}\cdot\frac1n$$

My Edit

I find that the sum can be written as

$$s=1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}(H_{n(n+3)/2+2}-H_{(n^2+n+2)/2})$$

Where $H_{k}=1+1/2+1/3+...+1/k$ is the harmonic number.

Convergence follows from the asymptoptic expansion of $H_{k}$ which leads to a series similar to that of log(2).

Comment: What do you mean by the "ranges of equal signs"?

Comment: @XanderHenderson + - ++ --- ++++ ...

Comment: I think he means that you add 2 terms, then subtract 3, then add 4, etc

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Those are not equal signs... those are addition and subtraction signs.  I am so very confused...

Comment: Please see my OP

Comment: equal not as =, but as the same sign

Comment: @RushabhMehta Oi... okay.  I get it now.  It might be better to say that "the lengths of the sequences of signs in the series grow linearly," or some such.

Comment: @XanderHenderson By "equal signs" he means "like signs."  Just an unfortunate choice of adjective.

Comment: Similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2430060/how-to-test-for-convergence-for-the-harmonic-series-with-irregular-binomial-si, and you should be able to apply the alternating series test to an appropriate subsequence of partial sums.

Comment: If anyone was wondering, the explicit form of this series is $$1 - \sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n-15}-1}2\rfloor}\cdot\frac1n$$

Comment: @Rushab Mehta very elegant and suprising formula.

Comment: Since $H_m=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^m-1}{x-1}\,dx$, I wonder if the given series has an explicit form in terms of simple integrals involving Jacobi theta functions.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio That is exactly the path I have been following. As I am not at home and have only my mobile phone available I did not find the combinations of Jacobi theta functions which give the two sums in question.